# Qt 6, Android 11 widget application, read and write to file. permission denied

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-permissions, read-write

hope can point me in the right direction on how to fix my application so i could read and write a simple .txt file.

i think i have tried all solutions out thier is on the world wide web, but hit me with what i should try.

things i have tried:

```
    bool value = QJniObject::callStaticMethod<jboolean>("android/os/Environment","isExternalStorageManager");
    if(!value){
        QJniObject filepermit = QJniObject::getStaticObjectField("android/provider/Settings","ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCES_PERMISSION","Ljava/lang/string;");
        //you must changing the YOURPKGNAME at below
        QJniObject pkgName = QJniObject::fromString("package:org.qtproject.example.robotinterfaceandroidqt");
        QJniObject parsedUri = QJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod(
                        "android/net/Uri",
                        "parse","(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/net/Uri;",
                         pkgName.object<jstring>());
        QJniObject intent("android/content/Intent",
                          "(Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/net/Uri;)V",
                          filepermit.object<jstring>(),parsedUri.object());
        QtAndroidPrivate::startActivity(intent, 0);
    }else{
        qDebug() << "NEW PERMISSION IS NOT GRANTED";
    }
```

this gives me a prompt screen to allow acces but in allow acces to all files it is just all gray and cant be set to permission to acces all files.

The other thing i have tried:

```
int counter = 0;
bool permission(){
    auto result = QtAndroidPrivate::checkPermission("android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE").result();
    if(result == QtAndroidPrivate::PermissionResult::Denied){
        result = QtAndroidPrivate::requestPermission(QString("android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")).result();
        counter++;
        if(counter > 10)
            qDebug() << "CANNOT GIVE THAT KIND OF PERMISSION";
        permission();
    }else{
        counter = 0;
        return true;
    }
return false;
}
```

have also tryied that with `EXTERNAL_READ_STORAGE` and write even with qts own `QtAndroidPrivate::Storage` with out any luck.

i am on sdk 31 building app towards android 11 using qt, cmake,

UPDATE and clarify.

in my app i try and create a txt file to save JSON data it create a file on the device but i cannot open and write to the file. the error it gives is

<E Qt JAVA : openParcelFdForContentUrl: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider uri content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/62.txt from pid=2455, uid=10179 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()>

and i have tried with the following permission request:

```
auto result = QtAndroidPrivate::checkPermission("android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS").result();
if(result == QtAndroidPrivate::PermissionResult::Denied){
    result = QtAndroidPrivate::requestPermission(QString("android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS")).result();
  }
```

any ideas ?

the whole file thingy:

```
 QString  filename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName();
filename = filename + ".txt";
qDebug() << "the file name is : " + filename;
ui->startPageProgramName->setText(test.toString());
auto result = QtAndroidPrivate::checkPermission("android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS").result();
if(result == QtAndroidPrivate::PermissionResult::Denied){
    result = QtAndroidPrivate::requestPermission(QString("android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS")).result();
  }
QFile file(filename);
if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)){
    qDebug() << file.errorString();
    return;
}else{
QTextStream out(&file);
out << "QString::fromStdString(mainPro_->programToString())";
qDebug() << &out;
out.flush();
out << "testing som more";
out << "agian";
file.close();
}
```

Comment: Permission to which file path is denied?

Comment: i have updated the question so gives a better understanding

Comment: I see no file path. And i see no code that created a file.

Comment: #blackapps. sorry for that but is is the basic getsavefile have also tried with getSaveFileUrl() with no luck

Comment: You do not need MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to create files in public directories on external storage. You only need READ/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on Android 12- devices. Please remove all the permission stuff as it is only confusing.

Comment: Further it is still unclear wher you got that content scheme for a file in Downloads from.

Comment: i have tried only with READ/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissioncheck and request without any luck.  the file path and create file is from Qt opens a file explorer with save file. or i dont know what you are looking for as android programming is fairly new to me. it works if i run it as a basic qt widget program on my laptop.

Comment: And i have no idea what you mean with `create file is from Qt opens a file explorer with save file. `. Isn't that file created by your app? And as a programmer you should be able to mention full path.

Comment: from the QFileDialog::getSaveFileUrl(); i get the full path of the file"content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload%2Ftest.txt"

Comment: That is no full path from a file system. Its a content scheme from a file provider. A very valid scheme. Know how to use it! If you got such a content scheme then not one permission was needed. So why are you messing around with permissions?

Comment: becourse when i try to write to the file it gives me the error as described therfore in my thoughts was that i have to request permission when it clearly gives me an error that permission is denied.

Comment: For the second time: remove all that permission stuff. Just show code to obtain the content scheme an code where you try to write to it.

Comment: finaly i got it to work. thanx @Blackapps for beeing persistent on focusing on the path wich lead me to that i did not get the correct path to the file. the code: '    QUrl test = QFileDialog::getSaveFileUrl();
    QString  filename = test.toDisplayString();
    filename = filename;
    QFile file(filename);
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        qDebug() << file.errorString();
        return;
    }else{
    QTextStream out(&file);
    out << "HELLO WORLD" << Qt::endl;
    qDebug() << out.string();
    out.flush();
    file.close();
    }'

Comment: @Blackapps do you know why my files in android is stores as numbers and not by thier names? My filepath example is: "content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/75" and if i try to specific write a filename let say : content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/Qt.txt it gives me the permission denied.

Comment: Do you know why you did not remove all that permission stuff although it was asked twice?

Comment: i had tried multiple times, without all the permission stuff, if i was not clear in my comments. The thing i did not was followed the path i got. right now i get a path from android with a number as my file name, instead of the actual filename. and if i try to save a file with the specified filename as text it gives me permission.Denied error. It works with the numbers i can read and write to the file but i would like my app to see the filename.